# Grant access to SpreadSheet for Service Account

Tags: google-sheets, service-accounts

I am trying to automate some tasks in Google Spread Sheet with Python. So far I have created a service account in GCP, enabled Google Sheet API, and downloaded the credential file to my local folder. I use `gspread` package and below is the code for testing:

```
import gspread

gc = gspread.service_account(filename='./credentials.json')
spreadsheet = gc.open(GOOGLE_SHEET_URL)
worksheet = spreadsheet.sheet1
values_list = worksheet.get_all_values()

print(values_list)
```

I have also added the service account `...iam.gserviceaccount.com` as an editor in my spread sheet, but I still got the `Exception SpreadSheetNotFound`. What did I miss in this setup?

Comment: As additional information. if you want to retrieve Class Spreadsheet using the URL, it seems that you can also use `open_by_url`. [Ref](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.12.1/api/client.html#gspread.Client.open_by_url) And, if you want to retrieve Class Spreadsheet using the spreadsheet ID, it seems that you can also use `open_by_key`. [Ref](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.12.1/api/client.html#gspread.Client.open_by_key)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `gc.open()` can only work with the title, not the URL of the spreadsheet.